# erlang make error on mac osx 10.7.x

Tags: macos, erlang

I am trying to install otp R14B04 release on mac osx.

`./configure` goes well but `make` gives me this error:

```
make -f i386-apple-darwin11.3.0/Makefile TYPE=opt
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
cd lib && \
      ERL_TOP=/Users/abhinavsingh/Documents/otp_src_R14B04 PATH=/Users/abhinavsingh/Documents/otp_src_R14B04/bootstrap/bin:${PATH} \
        make opt SECONDARY_BOOTSTRAP=true
=== Entering application hipe
erlc -W  +debug_info +inline -o../ebin hipe_rtl.erl
(no error logger present) error: "Error in process <0.1.0> with exit value: {{badfun,[<<5 bytes>>,<<54 bytes>>,<<9 bytes>>,<<3 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<19 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<8 bytes>>,<<8 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<2 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<15 bytes>>,<<4 bytes>>,<<57 bytes>>,<<5 bytes>>,<<1 byte>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<10 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<6 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,<<6 bytes>>,<<12 bytes>>]},[{erlang,apply,2}]}\n"
```

any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: Configuring erlang with following options `CFLAGS=-O0 ./configure  --enable-threads --enable-darwin-64bit` make it work perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a known MacPorts issue. For details, please refer to:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31698